# Cannot find type 'AppSettings' in scope in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I opened my old ios project from the new Xcode(14.3.1). It cannot build because of this issue. It worked earlier in Xcode(8).
This error come when I build the project. I set up and install the pod correctly. but the build failed.

code :

```html
private var appSettings: AppSettings? = nil
```